# css toolbar failure

Tags: html, css

i'm failing miserably trying to work out how to create a toolbar in css. "all" i'm trying to do is create a 22x22 button toolbar of 4 buttons.

I have this png:  [image: the toolbar] and this code:

```
<style>
#nav {background: url(content/images/crtoolbar.png) no-repeat;height: 22px;width: 88px;}
#nav span {display: none;}
#nav li {list-style-type: none;float: left;width: 22px;}
#nav a {height: 22px;display: block;}
</style>

<ul id="nav">
    <li id="b1"><a href="#"><span>b1</span></a></li>
    <li id="b2"><a href="#"><span>b2</span></a></li>
    <li id="b3"><a href="#"><span>b3</span></a></li>
    <li id="b4"><a href="#"><span>b4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Which displays the bitmap ok, but the selection/hrefs are offset to the left by, roughly, 2 buttons and I can't work out how to "push" the buttons over or "drag" the hrefs back.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser might have a default padding for `ul`.

```
#nav { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Reset CSS will let you begin your projects with sane defaults across all browsers. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the answers by jimworm and Rikudo:

If you really only have colors as buttons, you may use CSS only:

```
<style>
/* insert css reset here */

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline; }
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px; height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 25px; }
#b1 { background: #0ff; }
#b2 { background: #000; }
#b3 { background: #00f; }
#b4 { background: #f00; }
</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="b1"><a href="#">b1</a></li>
        <li id="b2"><a href="#">b2</a></li>
        <li id="b3"><a href="#">b3</a></li>
        <li id="b4"><a href="#">b4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the next step is to work out how to use sprites and draw a hover image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS reset. Most common:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```